# Analysing Asymptotic Bounds

Tags: algorithms

Prove the following using the definition of asymptotic order notation.

Example: $15n^3+ 10n^2+ 20 \in O(n3)$

Hint: Consider $C = 15 + 10 + 20 = 45$ and $n_0:= 1$. Then $0 ≤ 12n^3+ 11n^2+ 10 ≤ Cn^3$ for
all $n ≥ n_0$

A) $n^2+3n^2/2+\cos(n)\in O(n^2)$

Comment: Please use MathJax to typeset the equations.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the rules of the forum so your question won't get deleted.

Anyways here is how you prove if some function is in this remember the definition.

Proof : For $n^2+3n^2/2+\cos(n)$ to be in $O(n^2)$ there needs to $\exists c>0, \exists n_0 \in \mathbb N, \forall n \geq n_0$ so
$$n^2+3n^2/2+\cos(n)\leq c \cdot n^2 + n_0$$
$$n^2+\dfrac{3}{2}n^2+\cos(n)\leq c\cdot n^2 +n_0$$
$$\dfrac{5}{2}n^2+\cos(n)\leq \dfrac{5}{2}n^2+ 1 \leq c\cdot n^2+n_0$$
chose $c=4$ and $n=2$ and then obviously $$\dfrac{5}{2}n^2+ 1 \leq 4\cdot n^2+2$$
so therfore $$n^2+3n^2/2+\cos(n)\in O(n^2)$$
$\square$